# Syntax error for makecert.exe tool

Tags: certificate, makecert

Did I missed anything during this?

I am running a this command from command prompt in Windows 7 to create a certificate but it is **showing a syntax error**.

```
Command I ran:
makecert.exe "c:\1\Test.cer" -a sha1 -n "CN=AppGuid" -sr LocalMachine -ss My -sky signature -pe -len 2048  

Output I got:
Usage: MakeCert [ basic|extended options] [outputCertificateFile]
Basic Options 
-sk
-ss
-sr
.
.
.
```

Did I missed anything during this?

Comment: Also, this should probably be on SuperUser.com or ServerFault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you can see from the format it says MakeCert [basic] [output file].

The last item in your command is not the output file, so theres one thing wrong. As for the rest, I would assume that "C:\1\test.cer" is not an option, so that is probably wrong too.